# What is the correct way to structure a high volume log record

Tags: sql, logging, database-performance

I have a requirement to log application events in a SQL 2012 database.  The basic record structure requirement is pretty simple:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog]
(
   [ProcessId] INT NOT NULL,
   [ApplicationId] INT NOT NULL,
   [Created] DateTime NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_EventLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProcessId],[ApplicaionId],[Created] ASC)
)
```

The problem I am having is one of performance.  Up to 1 million events per day can be generated and as the number of rows increase, the insert performance is diminishing - to the point where the logger will not be able to keep up with the events.

I am already writing batches of logs out to a intermediary plain text files and then processing these files using a service running separately from the main application logger.

I suspect that the culprit may be maintaining the index and I would like some advice on how I can approach this problem more efficiently/effectively.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered range partitioning?

Comment: I have not.  To be honest, I had not heard of the term before but I will investigate - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause of the performance problem is probably the choice of columns forming the clustered index.

In a clustered index, the data is actually stored in the leaf-level pages of the index, in the order defined by the index key columns. Hence, in your table, the data is stored in the order `ProcessID, ApplicationID, Created`.

Without seeing your data, I would assume that log entries are being created as time passes for a variety of `ProcessID`s and `ApplicationID`s. If this is the case, for every insert, SQL will actually be inserting each log entry at the appropriate point in the middle of your log table. This is more time-consuming for SQL Server to do than inserting records at the end of the table. Also, when an inserted record cannot fit on the appropriate page, a page split will occur which will result in the clustered index being fragmented - which will decrease the performance further.

Ideally, you should aim to have a clustering key that is a small as possible while also being unique. Therefore one approach would be to create a new ID column as an identity and create a clustered index on that. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog]
(
  [EventLogId] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  [ProcessId] INT NOT NULL,
  [ApplicationId] INT NOT NULL,
  [Created] DateTime NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_EventLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EventLogId])
)
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, this was indeed the problem.  I have added the simple PK as you suggested and added individual indexes for the three data fields and I am now seeing a consistent execution time for inserting new records.  Thank you for your advice and explanation.